# Getting Error in angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I'm running a test in `AngularJ`s but this error comes up in console!!

```
 Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {"data":[{"brand":"Samsung A7 Prime","color":"Gold","price":24500,"img":"img/Chrysanthemum.jpg"},{"brand":"iPhone 6 Plus","color":"White","price":29899,"img":"img/Desert.jpg"},{"brand":"Acer Liquid Zest","color":"Silver","price":6999,"img":"img/Hydrangeas.jpg"},{"brand":"HTC Desire 107","color":"Black","price":15799,"img":"img/Koala.jpg"}],"status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"data/items.json","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"OK"}
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/filter/notarray?p0=%7B%22data%22%3A%5B%7B…son%2C%20text%2Fplain%2C%20*%2F*%22%7D%7D%2C%22statusText%22%3A%22OK%22%7D
        at angular.js:66
        at angular.js:20683
        at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15351), <anonymous>:4:299)
        at regularInterceptedExpression (angular.js:16459)
        at Scope.$digest (angular.js:18002)
        at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18280)
        at done (angular.js:12378)
        at completeRequest (angular.js:12604)
        at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:12532)
```

**JSON**:

```
[{
    "brand": "Samsung A7 Prime",
    "color": "Gold",
    "price": 24500,
    "img": "img/Chrysanthemum.jpg"
}, {
    "brand": "iPhone 6 Plus",
    "color": "White",
    "price": 29899,
    "img": "img/Desert.jpg"
}, {
    "brand": "Acer Liquid Zest",
    "color": "Silver",
    "price": 6999,
    "img": "img/Hydrangeas.jpg"
}, {
    "brand": "HTC Desire 107",
    "color": "Black",
    "price": 15799,
    "img": "img/Koala.jpg"
}]
```

**JavaScript**

```
$http.get('data/items.json').then(function(data){
        $scope.items = data;
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter: search | orderBy: order">
                            <img style="width: 50px; height: 50px; margin: 5px;" ng-src="{{item.img}}">
                            {{item.brand}} -- {{item.color}} -- {{item.price | currency: 'Php '}}
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeItem()">Remove Item</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: still error :'(

Comment: try `$scope.items = data.data`

Comment: it woooooooorks! THANKS MAAAAN :*

Answer (score 0):

The response data would be present in propert called data so change to

```
$http.get('data/items.json').then(function(data){
        $scope.items = data.data;
    });
```

Comment: It woooooorks! THANKS MAN. Your the best

Comment: Good to hear it. you can upvote or accept the answer ;)